# How can I list my mined coins using RPC? And spend them?

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc, block

I've mined a few blocks on a blockchain, and I'm trying to figure how to actually see them. What is the correct RPC command ? I've managed to see all the coinbase transactions thanks to `listtransactions`, and my `getbalance` output seems ok, but they don't show up in `listreceivedbyaddress` nor `listreceivedbyaccount`.

Comment: These are two different questions. Please edit your question to include only the first and place the second part to a new question.

Comment: @GeorgeKimionis [Here it is](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/36703/from-mining-to-sending-via-rpc)

Comment: @rmac to clarify, are you talking about Bitcoin *-regtest* or a Bitcoin-fork?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `listsinceblock` command to filter out the `mined` coins. `listsinceblock` contains a `category` field. The values you're looking for are:

- `generate`: for coins mined locally that are available for spending
- `immature`: same as above but coins cannot be spent yet

Comment: It seems to work, but why aren't two clients returning the same list? Since they both have access to the same list of transaction, I would have thought that the output should be the same (and that there was no way to know, from this command only, that it was possible to redeem a generate block)

Comment: @rmac what do you mean by "two clients"? Two different `bitcoin-core` instances? If so, each instance has its own wallet and so the results will be different.

Comment: @GeorgeKimionis Judging from the tags and the quote *"on **a** blockchain* I'm inclined to think this is a Bitcoin fork project stuck at the pre-mine phase. I've tried to clarify this, rmac, which is it mate? Bitcoin or a fork?

Comment: @WizardOfOzzie good point