# From mining to sending via RPC

Tags: json-rpc

Assuming that there is a magical `mineblocks` RPC command that can mine X blocks on demand, what is the complete set of command line commands to start a client, mine my coins to a specific address, see the mined blocks, get the reward and send them to an address XXX?

Answer (score 1):

1. Put your client into regtest mode. This allows you to mine an arbitrary amount of blocks very quickly. Add this to your bitcoin.conf

   ```
   regtest=1
   daemon=1
   ```
2. Generate the blocks. Run

   ```
   bitcoin-cli setgenerate true <number of blocks>
   ```

   where X is the number of block you want. You'll want at least 101 blocks.
3. See the mined blocks. Run

   ```
   bitcoin-cli getblockhash <index>
   ```

   to get the hash of block number `<index>`. Then take that hash and run

   ```
   bitcoin-cli getblock <hash>
   ```
4. Repeat Step 3 for each block you want.
5. Send the Bitcoins to a new address. Run

   ```
   bitcoin-cli getbalance
   ```

   to find out your balance. Run

   ```
   bitcoin-cli sendtoaddress <address> <amount>
   ```

If you don't need to see the contents of the block, you can skip steps 3 and 4.

Answer (score 0):

`setgenerate` has been removed. and now you can use `generatetoaddress` to mine.

```
# generatetoaddress
generatetoaddress 1 2NDyXhf4i44Vqpy9FvPHXkw8ccA2WtMkTe3
```